# Why is the `spi device` library faster than the Adafruit's MCP3008 library?

Tags: analog-to-digital

I was reading some values from a function generator using the MCP3008 ADC, however, I got 5 times as many samples with the spi device library than I did with Adafruit's MCP3008. Why is that the case? It seems that because Adafruit's library is specific to MCP3008, it should be faster, but is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SPI library uses the SPI hardware.

I suspect the Adafruit code was written before the SPI library was written and uses a technique called bit banging to access the MCP3008.  Bit banging will be much slower than using the SPI hardware.

Comment: [adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MCP3008](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MCP3008) uses hardware SPI if it's available.